# ushort a, ushort b from ( ushort )( a | b ) to a with constant b

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am working with data that is b and in more detail is described by a. Atleast that is how i understand it. Any further links to basic bitwise operations are appreciated. All objects i am looking at have b as 0x8000. I need to find out a from c.

I have:

```
ushort a
ushort b
```

a is from 2-5

```
b = 0x8000

ushort c = (ushort)( a | b )
```

can i and if yes how can i come from c to a?

I tried ( a & b ) but that leads me to b not a. I am realy stuck although i know it should be easy if possible if i would understand the operations.

Comment: The most correct answer has been deleted :(

Comment: @BenVoigt - that answere ignored `b = 0x8000`

Comment: @Henk: It doesn't matter what `b` is... once you perform an OR operation, you can't distinguish between whether a bit was set in one input or both.  Chris was right about that.

Comment: That's only true when the ranges overlap. In this case they are known to be disjunct. We use this every day when dealing with enum flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it's `c AND NOT b`.

```
ushort a2 = (ushort) (c & ~b);
```

but only because *a is from 2-5* and that is smaller than 0x8000.
When `a` and `b` start to overlap in bits you're stranded.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if a if smaller that b, which is true from the interval you give for a.

Both of these will work :

```
a = (ushort) (c & ~b)  
a = (ushort) c - b
```